# How do you create a SOAP service in CQ5 (AEM)

Tags: aem

Does anyone know how to create a SOAP service in CQ5? Found the following [link](http://www.pro-vision.de/content/medialib/pro-vision/production/adaptto/2011/110915_adaptto_slingcxf-pdf/_jcr_content/renditions/rendition.file/110915_adaptto_sling_cxf.pdf) but this looks more like a hack. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

adaptTo is one of the more technical conferences, so a presentation there should carry a lot of weight.

The long & short of it is you will want to find the OSGi versions of whatever XML libraries you wish to use and load them into Felix, then you have access to those libraries in your servlets/services/components (the felix kind).